# XML - get all values from tags into an array

Tags: javascript, xml

I have what I am sure is a very straightforward question! I have an xml document and, using AJAX, I am wanting to get the values from tags with the same name into an array. XML:

```
<data>
  <instance>
    <term>Dog</term>
    <clicks>11235</clicks>
  </instance>
  <instance>
    <term>Cat</term>
    <clicks>6309</clicks>
  </instance>
</data>
```

My Javascript:

```
console.log(xml.getElementsByTagName("clicks")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

This only seems to return the first value. How do you return them all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get all tags, and then use `.each()` to get all values:

```
$(xml).find('clicks').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).html());
});
```

or if you want to get an array, you can use `.map()` function:

```
var list = $(xml).find('clicks').map(function(){
   return $(this).html();
}).get();
```

Using d3.js you can do something like this:

Define a div in your DOM `<div></div>`

```
var list = d3.select('div')
          .html(xml)   // set the xml content
          .selectAll('clicks')
          .each(function(){
              console.log(this.innerHTML);
          });
console.log(list); //you can do what you want with all clicks elements
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using d3.js framework so can't use that with jQuery. Is there a way in JavaScript?

Comment: Look at this edit, I think this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try i wrote in java, I think you have to change the array part. hope this helps.

```
NodeList clicks = xml.getElementsByTagName("clicks")
int[] clickArray = new int[clicks.getLength()];
for(int i=0; i<clicks.getLength();i++){
  clickArray[i] = clicks[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(){
 var clicks = xml.getElementsByTagName("clicks");
 var result = new Array();
 foreach(var c in clicks){
    console.log(c);
    result.push(c.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
 }
 return result;
}
```

this should print all "click" tags. In your result array now are all values, but note that this just works, if the tag "structure" is always the one you posted above